How do we interpret probability?
Take the probability that when I roll the dice, there is 1/6 chance of getting a particular face in the future from the perspective of the past. But when we actually roll the dice, we only obtain one particular face with 100% chance at the moment when a certain face turns up.
I believe we have 3 options here
The probability of 1/6 reflects our ignorance of the future and the future outcome 1 is the actual matter of fact (true) .
The probability does really change from 1/6 to 1 , violating law of non-contradiction in classical logic. We may need temporal logic here.
The statement "There is 1/6 chance of getting a particular face upon the roll of dice" is neither true nor false, as it refers to non-existent states of affairs in the future. So we abandon the law of excluded middle.

How about the die roll has the propensity of a uniform probability distribution, and the realization of that roll is a particular outcome.  We tend to stop caring about the propensity and start caring about the outcome when we observe the outcome, and so tend to condition on different information after the fact.

Your non-Bayesian options seem confused: for example, a probability is always with reference to an event, and events having different probabilities doesn't mean that a probability has changed.

@ryang Unless you believe every possible future contingent becomes true in some other actual world (modal realism), then other possible events are just abstract, as opposed to facts in the actual world. So there is a contradiction if P event has 1/6 & 1 probability across time (past&future) , unless you involve temporal logic. Which is my 2nd proposal. You evaluate propositions w.r.t time after indexing them to time.

@Sam A probability is always with reference to an event and, tacitly, the probability model.

Probability is an abstract thing that models some reality in not necessarily perfect way. How well real world process reflects the abstract probability model is a big question that most scientists (especially physicists) ask every day. Typically we assume that it does and do lots of experiments until we are convinced that it is true. Either way, you should distinguish probability as a mathematical concept from real world processes.

This is asking for opinions, it is not a question about mathematics.

This is a very good and very deep question. While I have no claim on being an expert on these matters, this is my understanding:
Your point of view that "probability is a measure of ignorance" is very Bayesian. Consider the following experiment:

We pick up our die.
We roll our die with our eyes closed.
We look at the die. The roll is 1.

Let $A$ be the event that we roll a 1. Then at Step 1, $P(A) = 1/6$, expressing that we have no clue what the outcome will be. At Step 2, $P(A) = 1/6$ still, because even though the die is rolled, we don't have any information about the outcome. At Step 3, it is better to say $P(A|A) = 1$. The probability that the outcome is 1, given that we just saw it was 1, is 100%. We are certain.
Now suppose we are doing this experiment in Delphi, the home of a moderately famous Oracle. Before Step 1, the Oracle of Delphi (who we assume can actually tell the future) warns us that our roll will be odd. Call this piece of information $B$. Then we might say $P(A|B) = 1/3$.
In summary: Probability is conditional on what you know. There is no paradox.
